# SQL группировка данных, посчитать по пользователям и дням

Tags: mysql

Необходимо посчитать кол-во комментов пользователей по дням, в течении недели. Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT user_id as user, COUNT(created) as ad_call 
FROM `model_comments` 
WHERE user_id in (102,5,7) and 
created BETWEEN '2021-10-01' and '2021-10-07' GROUP by user_id
```

Такой запрос выводит сколько комментов у пользователя за неделю, но мне необходимо получить данные по дням пробовал считать по дням:

```
SELECT user_id as user, COUNT(created) as ad_call 
FROM `model_comments` 
WHERE user_id in (102,5,7) and 
created BETWEEN '2021-10-01' and '2021-10-02' GROUP by user_id
```

Но тогда приходится делать 7 запросов, что неудобно.
Пробовал так:

```
SELECT user_id as user, COUNT(created) as ad_call, created 
FROM `model_comments` 
WHERE user_id in (102,5,7) and 
created BETWEEN '2021-10-01' and '2021-10-07' GROUP by user_id, created
```

Но из-за того что формат даты Y-m-d H:i:s, секунды не будут совпадать, и соответственно строки не группируются.
Возможно ли получить количество комментов пользователей сгруппированных по ним и по дням?

Comment: Вроде бы получилось как то, заменил created на DATE(created)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id as user, COUNT(created) as ad_call, DATE(created) as created
FROM `model_comments` 
WHERE user_id in (102,5,7) and 
created BETWEEN '2021-10-01' and '2021-10-07' GROUP by user_id, DATE(created)
```

Вот так получилось